# gerar arquivo PDF em php

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf, dompdf

olá, tenho uma demanda pra fazer mas não estou conseguindo

Estávamos com um erro em uma página que não estava gerando um arquivo PDF para download do usuário, um outro desenvolvedor até entao tinha descoberto a causa, estavamos usando um arquivo de exportação de relatórios que possuía radar, e o relatório em questão não tem, entao ele tenta gerar uma imagem que nao é possivel

Apontamos entao um novo arquivo de exportacao, e teria que ajustar todo o PDF para esse relatorio que nao possui o radar

segue a baixo o codigo que ja possui nesse arquivo de exportacao

se alguem tiver alguma dica ou qualquer coisa por ai to meio perdida

````
$path = "../";
require_once $path.'db/conn.php';
//echo var_export($_REQUEST,true); exit ;
require_once $path.'assets/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';



$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'format' => 'A4',
            'default_font' => 'dejavusans'
]);
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='utf-8';
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = 0;
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage(
    $path.'img/logo_actum2.png',
    0.2,
    '',
    array(10,10)
);
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;

$html = "
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
 <body> ";

$html .= "<table align='center'>";
$html .= " <tr>";
$html .= "  <td><center><h3 style='color:#00529c'>".$_REQUEST['titulo']."</h3></center><br>";   
$html .= "      <center><h4>Empresa: ".$_REQUEST['empresa']."</h4></center>";   
$html .= "      <center><h4>Nome: ".$_REQUEST['nome']."</h4></center>";





$html .= "</body>";
$html .= "</html>";

$mpdf->SetJS('this.print();');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output($_REQUEST['nome_relatorio']." - ".$_REQUEST['nome'].".pdf","D");

if(isset($_REQUEST['chart_uri'])) { 
    unlink ("../../tmp/".$file_tmp.".png");
}  

?> ```
````

Comment: Duplicada: [Erro ao gerar PDF na página PHP \[fechada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/581497/erro-ao-gerar-pdf-na-p%c3%a1gina-php)

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa. Ao invés disso, leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour] para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site e assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: Ol, minhas perguntas tinham sido fechadas

Comment: Não é permitida duplicação de postagens neste site. Queira seguir o que já foi orientado das outras vezes que perguntou. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o campo de comentários foi bloqueado nesta postagem, mas pode ser usado em sua postagem original.

Answer (score -3):

Olá! Pelo que entendi, você precisa ajustar o código para que o arquivo PDF seja gerado corretamente, utilizando um novo arquivo de exportação de relatórios que não possui radar.

Uma possível solução seria verificar se o relatório que está sendo gerado possui radar ou não, e então utilizar o arquivo de exportação correspondente. Você pode fazer isso adicionando uma verificação condicional no início do código para definir qual arquivo de exportação será utilizado:

Output($_REQUEST['nome_relatorio']." - ".$_REQUEST['nome'].".pdf","D");

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).